# Trying to dynamically display a model using Angular

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

I'm having trouble trying to dynamically display all o the json values in angular using `ng-repat`

here what what I'am hoping to replacate using hard coded values

html

```
 <div ng-repeat="user in users">
            {{user.userId}} {{user.userName}} {{user.password}}
        </div>
```

output

```
3 DAve password
4 bob password
4 kjdjkdj
1 names password2
```

I'm trying to write the angular repeat to be more generic so I can pass i any amount of json gather from a mongoose model. So far I've gotten

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in users">
        <td> {{key}} </td> <td> {{ value }} </td>
        </div>
```

With this loop I'm getting too much information with an output that follows

```
0 {"_id":"527a732fe5f8dabf5b00020c","userId":3,"userName":"DAve","password":"password"}
1 {"userId":4,"userName":"bob","password":"password","_id":"527abf6ebaa5eb8426000001","__v":0}
2 {"userId":4,"password":"kjdjkdj","_id":"527d62fc85612ab42b000001","__v":0}
3 {"__v":0,"_id":"528130182c5544b81f000002","password":"password2","userId":1,"userName":"names"}
```

how can i modify the following loop to output only the userName password and userId without having to explicitly declare them like in my first loop.

Comment: I assume `users` is a collection, so there are no keys, just indices.

Comment: So, you want something generic, but which only displays userName, password, and userId? Isn't that completely contradictory?

Comment: users is a collection

Comment: I agree with @JBNizet, what you want to do is an unnecessary abstraction. If you want to have a generic list of things, create a directive.

Comment: Sweet thanks I'll start looking at the angular documentation for directives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print all values, within `user` without knowing what or how many there are ahead of time you could use a second `ng-repeat` to iterate over the key value pairs of each object as such:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users">
    <div ng-repeat="(k, v) in user">
          {{v}} 
    </div>
</div>
```

This only prints the values since it looks like that's the part you're interested in.  Clearly you could print both.